# Convert array in json javascript - same key

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a PHP file where I have the name of the files of one folder and my objective now is to output this array as JSON.

My array looks like this:

```php
Array ( 
    [0] => teste3.pdf 
    [1] => teste2.pdf 
    [2] => teste.pdf 
    [3] => .. 
    [4] => . 
)
```

And I'd like my JSON structured like this:

```js
{
    "Documents": [
        {
            "NameDoc": "teste3.pdf"
        },
        {
            "NameDoc": "teste2.pdf"
        },
        {
            "NameDoc": "teste.pdf"
        },
     ]
}
```

I tried using `json_encode` but this alone doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: You have to loop through the array and create your own object.

Comment: why json encode  doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to tackle the problem at the source if you're using PHP to create the data:

```php
$arr = ['teste3.pdf', 'teste2.pdf', 'teste.pdf'];

$map = array_map(function($name){ 
    return ['NameDoc' => $name]; 
}, $arr);

echo json_encode([
    'Documents' => $map
]);
```

[**» Fiddle**](https://repl.it/IcXi)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array of files is called `MyArr`.

```
const obj = {
  Documents: MyArr.map(file => ({ NameDoc: file }))
}
```

Now do whatever you want to do with `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let myArray = [
  'teste3.pdf',
  'teste2.pdf',
  'teste.pdf'
];
let obj = {
  Documents: myArray.map( item => ({ NameDoc: item }))
};
let jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
```